# Выбрать один ImageView из трёх

Tags: android

Есть кастомный объект, ему нужно присвоить одно из трёх изображений, все изображения в папке `Drawable`.

Есть отдельный фрагмент, который отвечает за создание этого кастомного объекта, создание работает нормально, имя и количество + 1 boolean переменная указываются легко и правильно.

Как сделать выбор из трёх картинок так, чтобы во фрагменте создания объекта был блок, где будут изображены три *imageview*, и пользователь сможет выделить один (и только один) из них?

Если нужно - могу нарисовать и скинуть рисунок, как я это вижу.

Comment: Не не получается, мне нужно пинок в сторону чего гуглить, чтобы узнать как это сделать и собственно сделать. Здесь готовое решение не нужно, просто чтобы подсказали как называется этот объект, где можно выбрать один из ImageView, при этом чтобы пользователь видел, какой выбрал (какое-то выделение\подсветка)

Comment: тогда другой вопрос - может есть способ сделать так, чтобы при выделении 1й кнопки снималось выделение с других? (Более стандартное какое-то решение)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [виджеты-селекторы с группировкой](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/radiobutton.php) через `RadioGroup`.

Для ленивых нужно только кастомизировать `RadioButton` чтобы он показывал нужную картинку и не показывал текст.

Более правильным решением будет сделать кастомный класс, расширив класс `ImageView`, чтобы он реализовал интерфейс `Checkable` и `CheckedChangeListener` (может еще что то , что необходимо для работы в `RadioGroup`).

Вторым вариантом может быть обычный `ListView`  из трех позиций в режиме `SingleChoiceMode`, элементами которого будут ваши картинки - такой вариант реализовать, наверное, проще, нужно только что то придумать вместо чекбокса.

Comment: Вы уже 3й раз помогаете мне с моими нубо-вопросами, спасибо. И отдельное спасибо за совет книги Б.Харди и Б.Филлипса, очень хороша, доступна и понятна, спасибо!